# Using a function inside a tuple - Haskell

Tags: haskell

So I'm pretty new to haskell and having a bit of trouble finding out how to do this

So I have a type that consists of a list of identifiers and a function that when given the identifier it returns the associated value
An identifier is a string in this case

```
type Memory = ([Ide], Ide -> MemVal)
```

This is what the type is meant to look like and I'm trying to get the rest of an interpreter working using it

I want to be able to pass `Memory` an `Ide` and have it return an `MemVal` but I'm having trouble using the list or the function as they are inside the tuple

Closest I've gotten is

```
exp_semantics (I ident) (Memory, i, o) =
    case (Memory (fst Memory),ident) of ....
```

The idea was the pass Memory a tuple of `([current Identity list], ident)`. I know that `Ide -> MemVal works as expected. But I get

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘[Ide] -> Ide -> MemVal’
            with actual type ‘([Ide], Ide -> MemVal)’
```

I'm very lost so any help will be awesome.

I think I'm missing how to use functions and lists inside of a tuple as well as types

Comment: I think it would help here to first define a signature for `exp_semantics`. Especially since I'm not sure what you aim to do with this function.

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking, especially as the brief snippets included use the *type* `Memory` where a *value* is required. But the `snd` function extracts the second value of a pair, and if used on a `Memory` value is a function that accepts an `Ide`.

Comment: it looks as if your syntax is way way off. so much so that it is hard to see what you mean. either explain it in English better, or read up on syntax, or ask simpler, smaller questions, :) about every little bit of your program separately. better yet, [mcve]..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably make that

```
data Memory = Memory
       { identifiers :: [Ide]
       , memvals :: Ide -> MemVal }
```

In that case the syntax for *pattern matching* would actually look similar to what you wrote, in particular you'd have the *value constructor* `Memory` turning up in patterns.

```
exp_semantics (I ident) (Memory i o) = ...
```

With `type Memory = ...` however, `Memory` is **only a type synonym**. It's basically no more than a preprocessor macro for a type, that's resolved before the actual compilation and doesn't appear at runtime in any way at all. In that case, the pattern match should merely be

```
exp_semantics (I ident) (i, o) = ...
```

In either case, you'll already have deconstructed the type with the pattern match, so no need anymore to juggle with accessors like `fst`. So it should be just

```
     case o ident of ....
```